# map nginx $request_uri to port

Tags: nginx, http, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to create a map between nginx $request_uri and $port
I have many location and each location works with its own port.
for example I have:

```
location /path1 {
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:10000
}

location /path2 {
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:10001
}
```

I want this:

```
map $request_uri $port {
  /path1 10000;
  /path2 10001;
}

location $request_uri {
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:$port
}
```

How can I config like this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but this approach should work:

```
http {
    map $reqest_uri $port {
        ~^/path1 10000;
        ~^/path2 10001;
        default 9000;
    }
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:$port;
    }
}
```

How it works:

`location /` catches requests to all paths (unless there are more specific matches). Then nginx resolves the value for `$port` variable by running it through the map.

In the map, we use a regular expression for prefix matching the URI. Otherwise that match would be exact match, which wouldn't likely work.